# How to save a state when the user switches from the app/closes it? (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to save some list in a file for which I have already created a method. Right now, my app saves this info to the file only when the uses presses a certain button. For instance, I want to invoke the saving to file method when the user clicks away or closes the app. I saw that I cannot override the onPause() function in Jetpack Compose. I am am using kotlin for all of these. Also, I thought I could update the list every time it get bigger/ it shortens but I am afraid this action is going to be very perfrormance-eating. I tried with coroutines, BUT I CANNOT INVOKE them, I get an error that tells me that they need to be composables as well. Thanks for sticking to all of this!

This is for like a liked-items page that updates on a list.

Comment: "I saw that I cannot override the onPause() function in Jetpack Compose" - Where did you see that? Compose is a UI toolkit, independent of the Activity lifecycle.

Comment: I thought maybe you could use that to see when the app pauses? But you are right... it has nothing to do with the UI toolkit